# How to display a list horizontally with fixed number of columns dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to display a list horizontally with 3 columns , and it comes to new line automatically if the columns gets filled up. I am trying to code it using php but not getting any results. so , please if anyone can provide some way to make it possible. I am attaching the snapshots :[Image Snapshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4se2qp3it3qp22/p.jpg?dl=0)

```
  <li class="dropdown menu-item">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Electronics</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-menu" >
                                    <li class="yamm-content" >
                    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col-md-4" >
                            <ul class="list-unstyled" >
                                    <table>
                                        ?php  
                                            $cnt=0;

                                            while($cnt>0)
                                            {
                                                if($cnt==0)
                                                {   
                                                     ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                                    <td>
                                                        li><a href="#" style="font-weight:bold">Laptops And its accesories</a>&#9658

                                                      <ul >
                                                         <li><a href="#">HDD</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">DVD Player</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Motherboard    </a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Mouse and Keyboards</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Headphone</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
                                                         <li><a href="#">Data Cards </a></li>

                                                    </ul>



                                                                        </li>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <?php

                                                            $cnt=$cnt+1;

                                                            if($cnt>2)
                                                            {
                                                                $cnt=0;

                                                            }                                                                       
                                                         ?>
                                                </tr>

                                                </table>




                                         </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">


                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">




                            </ul>


                        </div>




                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: please if you can't help someone , don't downvote my question atleast . Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 loops something like this

```
for(;$i<$total;)
new row
for($j=0;$j<3;$j++)
$i++
display content
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, use "modulo", like this :

```
<table>
  <tr>
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($menu as $item) {
  if($i % 3 == 0) {
     // This will be executed 1 in 3 times.
     echo "</tr><tr>";
  }
  echo "<td>".$item."</td>"
}
?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It's just an exemple, the HTML generated here will not necessarily suit your code.

You can use CSS instead !

```
<ul>
  <li>Menu 1</li>
  <li>Menu 2</li>
  <li>Menu 3</li>
  <li>Menu 4</li>
  <li>Menu 5</li>
  <li>Menu 6</li>
</ul>

<style>
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    list-style: none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Sir , i have edited my question , your answer seems easy , but i am confused how to add it in my code .

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Vertical Columns

If you dont mind about [**IE9< compatability**](http://caniuse.com/#search=column), you can use CSS columns for this

```css
ul {
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    column-count:3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>column item 1</li>
    <li>column item 2</li>
    <li>column item 3</li>
    <li>column item 4</li>
    <li>column item 5</li>
    <li>column item 6</li>
    <li>column item 7</li>
    <li>column item 8</li>
    <li>column item 9</li>
</ul>
```

### 2. Horizontal ordering

If you want the blocks to display in horizontal order, technically this isnt a question of columns but can be achieved using:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>column item 1</li>
  <li>column item 2</li>
  <li>column item 3</li>
  <li>column item 4</li>
  <li>column item 5</li>
  <li>column item 6</li>
  <li>column item 7</li>
  <li>column item 8</li>
  <li>column item 9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sir , your code works but gives some weird output , i have posted my code too in which i am trying to implement it . So , if you can suggest based on that would be very helpfull sir.